# Why clearInterval() works only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

The basic idea is to identify if the page has a video, wait until it's over and then keep sliding the pages that don't contain the video with interval of 30 sec. It clears interval and waits until it finishes only once. In the second time it just keeps sliding like other pages.

```js
function getPage(i) {
  return p[i];
}

var pages = '@ViewBag.pages';
var p = JSON.parse(pages.replace(/(&quot\;)/g, "\""));
var i = 0;
var mi = p.length - 1;
var interval;
var frame = document.getElementById("slider");
var frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
frame.onload = function() {
  if ($(document).find("iframe").contents().find("video").length == 1) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log("interval was cleared successfully");
    console.log("the video is now playing!");
    var video = document.getElementById('slider').contentWindow.document.getElementById('video');
    video.onended = function() {
      console.log("video is finished!");
      i++;
      if (i > mi) {
        i = 0
      }
      frame.src = getPage(i);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("video is not found");
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      i++;
      if (i > mi) {
        i = 0
      }
      $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: getPage(i),
        type: 'GET',
        success: function() {
          frame.src = getPage(i);
        }
      });

    }, 10000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `clearInterval` is not getting called when the page doesn't have a video.

Let's take the following scenario, you have 2 pages without video and 1 page with video in that order

1. First page is loaded, setInterval is started and stores the reference in variable `interval`.
2. After 10000ms next page is loaded, the previous setInterval is not cleared as the page doesn't have a video, and `interval` is updated with a new setInterval. Now you have two setIntervals running, lets say `interval1` and `interval2`
3. After 10000ms, this time 2 setIntervals are executed, `interval1` moves the page to 3rd page and `interval2` moves the page to 1st page.
4. You keep creating new setIntervals until you go to a page with video and when you do reach the page with video, you are clearing only one interval which is the last one. That still leaves all other intervals alive, which keep updating your page.

#### Solutions:

1. Run clearInterval unconditionally inside iframe.onload

```
var interval;
frame.onload = function() {
  interval && clearInterval(interval);
  if ($(document).find("iframe").contents().find("video").length == 1) {
  } else {
    interval = setInterval(function() {}, 10000);
  }
}
```

2. Use setTimeout as you want it to be executed only once.

```
frame.onload = function() {
  if ($(document).find("iframe").contents().find("video").length == 1) {
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {}, 10000);
  }
}
```

> **PS:** I prefer the second one